# How to search through two list members?

Tags: c#, string, visual-studio-2010, list, hashset

I have the following class:

```
    public class fixFirstDuplicate
    {
        public string firstParam { get; set; }
        public string secondParam { get; set; }
    }
```

and the list:

```
public static List<fixFirstDuplicate> firstDuplicate = new List<fixFirstDuplicate>();
```

the list is full of values for firstParam and secondParam that each correspond to each other. it's basically a table, where the first firstParam is associated with the first secondParam and so on.

then I have:

```
List<string> conLines = new List<string>();
```

I want to look through conLines, and everytime a string contains both firstParam and secondParam, perform a method on that string.

If I were doing this with just one list, say firstParam, I would use HashSet, but I don't know how to do the equivalent given I have firstParam and secondParam

Comment: so, conLines is firstParam and secondParam concatenated, like conLine = firstParam + secondParam?

Comment: Is your question _"How to determine a string contains both firstParam and secondParam"_? How can one string contain two strings, are they concatenated using a separator character? Do you have trouble iterating over the list? Do you know Linq?

Comment: They will be separated by at least one space. I do not know Linq well.

Comment: To be clear: you can have a `fixFirstDuplicate` with `firstParam = "foo1"`  and `secondParam = "bar2"` and your `conLines` containing `"foo1 bar2"`, then you want to return that `fixFirstDuplicate` instance? And not for `"bar2 foo1"` nor `"foo1 foo1"`?

Comment: You couldn't do this operation using a hash based set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check if `conLines` contains both `firstParam` or `secondParam` like:

```
var query = firstDuplicate.Where(r => conLines.Contains(r.firstParam) &&
                                   conLines.Contains(r.secondParam));
```

EDIT: If you want to call a method when you find a match and the order is important to you then you can use a simple `foreach` loop like:

```
foreach (var item in firstDuplicate)
{
    string matchingString  = conLines.FirstOrDefault(r => 
                              (r.IndexOf(item.firstParam)>= 0 && 
                              r.IndexOf(item.secondParam) >= 0) &&
                              (r.IndexOf(item.firstParam) < 
                               r.IndexOf(item.secondParam)));

    if(matchingString != null)
    {
        //CallYourMethod(matchingString);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok. But in between each iteration that it finds a match (every time a set of firstParam and secondParam is found in conLines), I want to perform a method.

Comment: You would call the method for each result returned by that query.

Comment: This can return false positives if the parameters are substrings of each other or when they are out of order.

Comment: I don't think order matters: "everytime a string contains both firstParam and secondParam". If it did, you could modify to say `&& conLines.IndexOf(r.firstParam) < conLines.IndexOf(r.secondParam)`

Comment: But we don't know that. You shouldn't jot down the first answer that comes in mind when OP's question is wildly interpretable. Use comments to ask for clarification first. And your edit still doesn't cater for the substring case.

Comment: That's a good point that I should have specified. Order matters.

Comment: @user2340818, in that case you can use a loop, I have modified the answer.

Comment: I think he means order of the words in the string, as in the `firstParam` needs to appear before `secondParam` in the string.

Comment: @Habib Thank you! How would I get the index of conLines where the firstParam and secondParam were found?

Comment: @user2340818, I have modified it again, instead of index you will get the string from the `ConLines`

Comment: @mclaassen, ohhhh okkk. That makes it much clear and my answer is not right in that case.

Comment: @Habib I think you still need to account for the order of the words in the string.

Comment: I can add @Habib's comment from earlier: && conLines.IndexOf(r.firstParam) < conLines.IndexOf(r.secondParam)

Comment: @user2340818, I have added that in the answer, it will compute the index twice, once for making sure that it exists and later to check the order

Comment: @user2340818 You mean my comment ;)

Comment: @mclaassen ah my mistake, yes. Thank you both very much!

Comment: @Habib What if I want to know the index of each matchingString in conLines? At the end of the day, I want to look through conLines for matchingString, change things in that string, and then print out all of conLines, or, alternatively, print each line of conLine one at a time (whether it's a matchString or not).

Answer (score 1):

This code:

- Loops through all strings you want to examine
- Splits the string on space, removing empty elements
- Finds all entries in the `firstDuplicate` list that have parameters matching the input strings
- Adds them to the result `foundDuplicates`

You'll have to take care of:

- Validity of the strings in `conLines`
- Case sensitivity
- Handling multiple results per string and entries matching multiple strings

---

```
var foundDuplicates = new List<fixFirstDuplicate>();

foreach (var combinationToFind in conLines)
{
    // "They will be separated by at least one space."
    var parameters = combinationToFind.Split(new[] { ' ' },                  
                         StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

    var duplicatesForCombination = firstDuplicate.Where(d => 
                                                d.firstParam == parameters[0]
                                            && d.secondParam == parameters[1]);

    foundDuplicates.AddRange(duplicatesForCombination);
}
```

Now you can call your method for each entry in `foundDuplicates`.